# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, .net-3.5, format

I have this piece of code:

```
private string getTime(int time)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds, t.Milliseconds);
}
```

And later on in my application this part of code:

```
dataGridView_Trips.Rows[i].Cells["top_Tijd"].Value = (string)getTime(routeInfo[0]);
```

No matter how or what I try to cast it as a `string`, once it tries to set the Value of `Cells["top_Tijd"]` it will give me an error that, in this case, `getTime` returns a string `"17:46"` and tells me this is not a correct decimal format?

It's trying to set it as a strong but tell me that it is not a correct decimal value, why?

Edit1:

Tried adding dataGridView_Trips.Columns["top_Tijd"].ValueType = typeof(string); to no avail.

Edit2:

Tried to remove getTime and pasted in a hardcoded "test" and claims the same wants decimal even after setting it's valuetype.

Edit3:

Here's a screenshot of the Format behavior... (No Formatting.)
[image]

Comment: Well how is your DataGridView configured for that column? (`top_Tijd` isn't a very descriptive name, so it's hard to tell what it's meant to be...)

Comment: As a starter, you can remove the casting, as `getTime` already returns a string. Other than that, what does `getTime` return and what's the value of `routeInfo[0]` ?

Comment: Maybe your column is defined to accept decimals? Set it's `DataType` to `string`.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is set as a textbox. It is ment to contain a string like HH:MM.

Comment: @StefanM routeInfo[0] contains seconds as an integer. TimeSpan simply converts it to a HH:MM format. In this case 17:46. It doesn't matter what it formats to, however, the datagridview just wont'accept it. I just dont'understand why it doesn't just accept it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem: I've solved it changing the value type in the column of the MS Access Database binded to the dgv's column.

You can't change the type of a binded column directly from Visual Studio: if your column has a setted DataPropertyName, it's the name of the Db column that you've to change.

If you can't edit the db, you must copy column's values into a new not-binded column.

Comment: Thank you, I actually forgot about this question after solving it through a similiar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"17:46"` is not a Decimal. Your DataGridView probably has that column defined as a Decimal. You should change it to `TimeSpan`, `String` or something else more appropriate

Comment: The column is as default as it can be. But how would I go about changing it to accept the value as a string? It is ment to be a string, getTime returns a string. I want to store it as a string.

Comment: Also, I tried changing it's ValueType to typeof(string) but generates the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of things I would do differently here. First off - the format you want to use is: "h:mm" or "HH:mm" for your time. 
Secondly - use the DateTime.ToString(yourFormat) to format your dateTimes. Check out the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: It's not actually a date but just a duration/length of a ride/trip. Hence I chose to use TimeSpan.

Comment: Good punt - but TimeSpan.ToString() also exists - cheeck it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx - uses mostly same formatting string parameters - so you can use TimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm").

Comment: Thanks, but geTime still returns a "string" and I don't understand why the datagridview won't accept it.